# Webkit Developer Tools does not show parent domain cookies?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome, webkit

For an app I'm developing on sub.domain.com, I have cookies that I need from domain.com and sub.domain.com. Firebug+Firecookie shows me all the cookies that go out with each request, however when I use Developer Tools in Chrome I only see the cookie set on sub.domain.com.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No answer for this as of yet, so for now I'll make this the current workaround:

Open the developer console (cmd+option+i on the mac) go to the Console tab and enter:

```
document.cookie
```

This will show you all the cookies for the domain as well as any parent domain.