# Safari 6 Web Inspector: Can't see my domain-level cookie

Tags: cookies, safari

I am having a problem viewing a cookie value in Safari 6 developer tools.  Just to be clear - the cookie works fine.  I can see/fetch/echo the value of the cookie on the page.  However, I can't see it in the Storage section of Web Inspector.

I'm wondering if the problem is multi-level subdomains.  We have these:

www.domain.com
sub.domain.com
www.dev.int.domain.com (accessible only while on VPN)

We want this cookie accessible to all the domains, so we set a domain-level cookie like so (example):
Set-Cookie: UserLoginCookie=someencryptedvalue; Domain=.domain.com; Expires=Sun, 23-Mar-2014 00:02:56; Max-Age=31104000; Path=/; Version=1; HttpOnly

I'm looking in Web Inspector, in the Storage section, under Cookies.
When I load www.domain.com, I see the UserLoginCookie in the list.
When I load sub.domain.com, I see the UserLoginCookie in the list.
When I load www.dev.int.domain.com, I do NOT see the cookie, even though I can read/set it.

I've tried to google for this and search stackoverflow, but I've gotten nowhere.  Does anyone know if this is a Safari bug or if there's just a step/option that I'm missing somewhere?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is a Webkit based bug that Safari has yet to fix - [Webkit Developer Tools does not show parent domain cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108904/webkit-developer-tools-does-not-show-parent-domain-cookies)

There is no easy way to do it as Safari removed the ability to see individual cookies from the Security tab: ["Show Cookies" button missing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3206191?start=15&tstart=0) as per this [HOWTO](http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Cookies-Using-the-Safari-Web-Browser). I have also tried the "[Safari Cookies](http://www.sweetpproductions.com/safaricookies/)" plugin but it does not work as the cookie list did not refresh for me.

I've resolved to inspecting cookies with the 'document.cookie' in the developer console.